# Почти рефакторинг php

Tags: php

Есть файл, в нем, например, следуещее:

```
$delfull    = $path_to_90_directory.$filename; 
            unlink    ($delfull);
            }
            else 
                     {
                     exit ("Аватар должен быть в    формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>");
                             }
            }
```

Тут пробелы перед "=", в начале строки много пробелов. Есть ли такие программы, которые удаляют эти пробелы, чтобы улучшить читаемость кода?

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите эту разработку от моего друга, работает как часы: 
[**Вот**](http://irbis-team.com/15/1/11)

Answer (score 0):

Практически любой текстовый редактор умеет делать поиск и замену через регулярные выражения. Здесь подойдет `(\S)\s{2,}`. Это регулярное выражение найдет все многократные пробелы встречающиеся с середине строки. `(\S)` - захват непробельного символа слева, для того, чтобы не учитывать пробельные отступы в начале строки. Для замены используем строку `"\1 "`. Обратная ссылка `"\1"` вернет левый символ, а `" "` заменит многократные пробелы на однократные.

[image: Editor]

Comment: Ну а если эти пробелы будут в echo и они там должны быть?

Comment: То, этим методом, они там тоже будут обрезаны, и это меньшее из зол.

Также, можно посмотреть в строну настройки форматирования исходного кода в своей IDE...

Comment: Он там есть, но если код вставлять уже готовый, то он не форматируется.

Comment: Опция "Форматировать при вставке" обычно доступна в настройках.

Comment: Не подскажете где именно это находится в NetBeans?

Comment: Нашел - Исходный код - Формат))))

Answer (score 0):

В netbeans можно выделить код и нажать alt+shift+f или правой клавишей мыши и выбрать "формат"(в других редакторах должно быть что-то аналогичное). [Ну или запихни код сюда](http://irbis-team.com/15/1/11). Все эти действия приведут к форматированию кода в нормальный вид.
А вообще:
**Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живете". (с) Макконнелл, "Совершенный код".**